# JAXB and @XmlType propOrder attribute

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb

Having this method:

```
public Boolean isCorrect() {
    return correct;
}
```

I can't write:

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id", "description", "correct"})
```

because it seems like it is dependent on that the accessor methods are named `get..`. Is it possible to use `is..` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* create a type adapter or change the way JAXB retrieves variables for marshalling as suggested in the other answers but the problem here is your `Boolean` return type.

The JavaBeans spec only allows for a getter named `is<propertyName>` if the return type is primitive `boolean`, otherwise it should follow the usual convention of `get<propertyName>`.

This:

```
public Boolean isCorrect() {
    return correct;
}
```

should be changed to:

```
public boolean isCorrect() {
    return correct;
}
```

or:

```
public Boolean getCorrect() {
    return correct;
}
```

otherwise you may encounter other problems with libraries that use getters/setters to discover variables on your POJOs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation to your class, so JAXB will not care about your getters/setters signatures.

Comment: Instead of doing this I'd recommend that the OP names their getters/setters to follow JavaBeans conventions, see my answer.